# Emacs, how to fix 'make-variable-buffer-local not call at top level'?

Tags: debugging, emacs

I use doom Emacs.
Here is code in my `.doom.d/config.el.`
There is a warning `make-variable-buffer-local not call at top level` at `:defer t`

```
(use-package! py-isort
  :defer t
  :init
  (define-minor-mode python-isort-autosave-mode
    "Isort autosave mode."
    :lighter " Isort"
    :global nil
    (when (not (derived-mode-p 'python-mode))
      (error "Isort only works with Python buffers"))
    (if python-isort-autosave-mode
        (add-hook! 'before-save-hook :local #'py-isort-before-save)
      (remove-hook! 'before-save-hook :local #'py-isort-before-save)))

  (add-hook! 'python-mode-hook #'python-isort-autosave-mode))
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you have the `!` char appended to several function names? If those are not standard functions then your question is undefined.

Comment: And you don't show or say anything about what code is flagged as using `make-variable-buffer-local` not at top level.

Comment: IIRC those `!` symbols are defined by the Doom Emacs libraries.  I can't tell at a glance whether this is a more general `use-package` question, or a very Doom-specific question, though.

Comment: That said, I would firmly guess that the variable in question will be the buffer-local minor mode variable, and that the error could probably be avoided by moving that definition into a separate library (something like `python-isort-autosave-mode.el`), and just `require`ing that library in the `:init` section.